# PDF generation library for a delphi text editor

Tags: delphi, pdf, pdf-generation

I have this small word editor written in Delphi, I need a library to save/export the text as a PDF document.
Is there any good library, .dll file, preferably free, that gives this function? maybe converting it from a string, or the .rtf file to a PDF?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps [Synopse PDF engine](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/05/03/Synopse-PDF-engine) - it is Open Source (you can choose between MPL/GPL/LGPL license) and it has builtin export from RTF to PDF (see comment by A.Bouchez, author of the lib).

Comment: I wrote this library. ;) The engine as a ready-made export function, via the SQLite3Pages report class. See http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=41 You can directly export a RTF/RichtEdit content, as stated by http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=76

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of the feature as I'm not actually using it myself, just keeping an eye on it :)